# Questions about Hadoop And Hive And Presto

Tags: hadoop, hive, presto

I am looking into using Hive on our Hadoop cluster to then use Presto to do some analytics on the data stored in Hadoop but I am still confused about some things:

- Files are stored in Hadoop (some kind of file manager)
- Hive needs tables to store data from Hadoop (data manager)

  - Do both Hadoop and Hive store their data separate or does Hive just use the files from Hadoop? (in terms of hard disk space and so on?)
    -> So does Hive import data from Hadoop in tables and leave Hadoop alone or how must I see this?
- Can Presto be used without Hive and just on Hadoop directly?

Thanks in advance for answering my questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: files are stored in Hadoop Distributed File System (**HDFS**). Is that what you call Data manager?

Actually Hive can use both - "regular" files in HDFS or tables which are once again "regular" files with additional metadata stored in special datastore (it is called warehouse).

Concerning Presto - it has a built-in support for Hive metastore, but you can also write your own **connector plugin** for any data source.

Please read more info about Hive connector configuration [here](http://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html) and about connector plugins [here](https://gist.github.com/frsyuki/7553718).

Comment: I just want to be able to query the data in Hadoop, so I guess I need Hive tables that contain metadata about the files in Hadoop?

Comment: @darkownage I think you need **EXTERNAL TABLES**.
"The EXTERNAL keyword lets you create a table and provide a LOCATION so that Hive does not use a default location for this table. This comes in handy if you already have data generated."

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table1(id INT)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\054'
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
 LOCATION '<hdfs_location>';`
[source](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables)